# Script keeps timing WP site out. Any ideas where it comes from

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00xBw.jpg)

This script is generated by chrome. It runs till it times out the site. Any idea where it is coming from? or what is causing?

Comment: You haven't posted the script or any code at all, so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any extensions installed? If you do, that's probably why. Looking at how the page is loading a url from the chrome resource, it's probably a corrupted chrome extension. Try disabling each extension you have one by one, to see which one is causing the problem.